# Get border style in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

For example:

```
<div class="myel" style="border: dashed 1px #cc9900;background-color:#cc9900">Test</div>​
```

When i'm running this script:

```
alert( $("div.myel").css("background") );​
```

the result on firefox and chrome is :

```
rgb(204,153,0) none repate scroll 0% 0%
```

And for this script

```
alert( $("div.myel").css("background-color") );​
```

the result is :

```
rgb(204,153,0)
```

But when running this script:

```
alert( $("div.myel").css("border") );​
```

nothing appear on firefox but the result in chrome is:

```
dashed 1px rgb(204,153,0)
```

The same happens with 
`alert($("div.myel").css("border-color"));​` and `alert($("div.myel").css("borderColor"));​`

Comment: that sounds weird, http://jsfiddle.net/2GrLP/ ?

Comment: thanks this will work if the css is built-in HTML but if it's in css file this script will not work

Comment: Of course that fiddle won't work with CSS. `.attr` retrieves HTML attributes, if you don't have a `style` attribute it won't retrieve anything.

Comment: If you need to get at the style which is applied via an external stylesheet then this answer is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Comment: What's the actual question here?